# Check if product exists without exception in API

Tags: product, api, magento-community

Is there a way to check whether a product already exists in Magento using the SOAP API that doesn't require using exception handling for the control flow?

I have the following code that works, but I wouldn't say it follows best practices.

```
Dim productExists As Boolean
Try
    Dim webService As MagentoService = New MagentoWS.MagentoService
    Dim productInfo As catalogProductReturnEntity = webService.catalogProductInfo(sSessionId, sku, String.Empty, Nothing, "sku")
    productExists = True
Catch ex As SoapHeaderException
    productExists = False
End Try
```

I have to catch the SoapHeaderException and then use the fact that the exception was thrown to know that the product doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how `.NET`s SOAP API would handle this, but I'd try using the [`catalog_product.list` method](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html) with a SKU filter.  If the resulting list/array/collection/whatever-its-serialized-as is empty, then you know the product doesn't exist.

Per the comments below, the following code should get you that list

```
Dim productExists As Boolean 
Dim webService As MagentoService = New MagentoWS.MagentoService 
Dim filters As filters = New filters() 
filters.filter = {New associativeEntity() With {.key = "sku", .value = sku}} 

Dim productInfo As catalogProductEntity() = webService.catalogProductList(sSessionId, filters, String.Empty) 

productExists = productInfo.Count() > 0
```

Comment: like the idea with the list+filter combination!

Comment: This worked great. Can you add the sample code to your answer, and I will accept it.      Dim productExists As Boolean Dim webService As MagentoService = New MagentoWS.MagentoService
 Dim filters As filters = New filters()
 filters.filter = {New associativeEntity() With {.key = "sku", .value = sku}}
    Dim productInfo As catalogProductEntity() = webService.catalogProductList(sSessionId, filters, String.Empty)
    productExists = True

Comment: @RyanGates Code's up there — it looks like some (the length/emptiness check for `productInfo` maybe got cut off though?

Comment: You're correct, here's the rest: productExists = productInfo.Count() > 0.

Comment: @RyanGates All set!  If I missed something try gist for the code snipped and I'll edit things in place https://gist.github.com/